# Table row as column in Access form

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I am trying to create a form in Access based on a table and I would like to use the table's rowdata as the column title in the form.

What I mean is, I have a table as follows which shows the effort booked by employees towards specific projects on a monthly basis:

```
ProjectNo  EmployeeName  HoursBooked  Month/Year
23            Mark          68         01/01/2012
23            Mark          55         01/02/2012
54            John          22         01/02/2012
23            John          52         01/02/2012
```

...etc

and from this I would like to create a singular form where the data is displayed as follows for each project. For example, for project 23:

```
Month/Year   Mark     John
01/01/2012   68        0
01/02/2012   55        52
```

and someone should be able to go to this form, edit the numbers and the table should reflect these changes.

Could someone guide me on how to achieve this? I have been trying to achieve this in Access but unfortunately my Forms knowledge is not that great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the wizard to create a crosstab query. It will give you what you want. You can set the Source Object of Subform Control to `Query.NameOfCrosstabQuery`.

However, you will not be able to edit form data based on a crosstab.

It is possible that someone will see an alternative solution if you say why you wish to present the data in this way.

EDIT some details on a possible approach: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Crosstabs%2C_forms_and_updating

Comment: Note also that crosstab queries yield changing column names, which makes it difficult to bind the columns to textboxes.

Comment: @Olivier Yes. If one must include this type of view, it is best to use a subform with the query as a source object, as suggested here, and thereby avoid the problem.

Comment: yes it is messy, you are going to have to open the crosstab query as a QueryDef in your code, execute it and iterate through the columns to find their names and alter the conrol source of your text boxes accordingly. To update you will need a dialog box that prompts for the new value then execute an UPDATE query to update the value in the database then requery the form

Comment: @ChrisPadgham You can set the Source Object of a subform to a query, no controls, no iterating, no actual subform, just a crosstab query.

Comment: @Remou, Interesting I wasn't aware of that it is not that user friendly though and it does not appear to respond to any events. How do you propose updating the figures in it.

Comment: @ChrisPadgham Perhaps you did not get a chance to read my original post?

Comment: @Remou Yes I was proposing a way you could edit the data in the crosstab, albeit not directly in the grid.

Comment: @ChrisPadgham It can be done, but it would require a textbox and a second subform. If you really want to know, I can provide more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Let say that 1st form is having name: FrmProject & project id is displayed in ProjectID control.
The second form is having name FrmProjectDetails. Considering that project data is stored in table TblPorjects.

On the Click event of ProjectID control in FrmProject you write the code as follow:

```
Private Sub ProjectID_Click()
docmd.open "FrmProjectDetails"
Form_FrmProjectDetails.RecordSource= "select * from TblProjects where ProjectID=" & Me.ProjectID
End Sub
```